# How to specify a different text color in react google chart's gantt chart?

Tags: reactjs, gantt-chart, react-google-charts

If I am using the gantt.palette option to specify the colors of the bar groups in my gantt chart, as discussed in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165271/customize-the-bar-colors-in-google-gantt-charts), is there a way to specify a different color for the text accompanying these items?